# Using FloatBarrier second column not filled

Tags: floats

I was hoping \FloatBarrier could place my image where I want it to be and wrap text around it, but the second column is not getting filled. Also I have been trying hard to put the image just below the Methodology. How do I enable filling the second column with text and place the image below the methodology?

[image]

```
\section{METHODOLOGY}\label{sec:METHODOLOGY}

The framework for this study is visualized in Figure~1 and described in detail below.

\begin{figure*}[tbp]
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=1.5\columnwidth]{figures/test_sites/process.png}
    \caption{MGWR Process.}
\label{fig:mgwr_process}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}


\subsection{Study Area}\label{sec:StudyArea}
The study area is shown in Figure~2. The NCR Plus bubble is a location in the Philippines that consists of the National Capital Region and four neighbor provinces namely Bulacan, Cavity, Laguna and Rizal. On March 22, 2021, the bubble setup was placed in a “Enhanced Community Quarantine” because of rising COVID-19 cases. A total of 108 sample points, representing each municipality and city, were used for MGWR analysis. These points are the centroids for each municipality and city inside the bubble since the reported COVID-19 cases were aggregated in a municipal and city level.
```

**UPDATE 1**

After using `dblfloatfix`, the image went too far and sort of find a location to fit in a bottom `[b]`. How can I force it to be placed just under where I want it to be -- methodology part?
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Removed `\FloatBarrier`, but my image still too far where it is referenced.

Comment: floatbarrier will force a page break which is what you are trying to avoid. By default latex does not support bottom spanning flotas so the `b` option is ignored, use packages such as `dblfloatfix` to allow the float at bottom of page

Comment: Thanks! However it went too far to my document (not the end of the document now). Its not yet under the methodology. How can I force that?

Comment: I updated my question for the image...

Comment: you haven't provided an example anyone can run so we can only give hints, You need to remove `\FloatBarrier` as that will prevent teh outcome you want, an ddouble column figures always come at the earliest on the next page, so move it earlier in the source file.

Comment: I already removed `\FloatBarrier`, here is a repo for that example: https://gitlab.com/cnpante/isprs. The image is `process.png`. I have tried different `[pos]` but image gets place too far methodology.

Comment: you haven't removed it from the code shown here, that is the code that you are asking about. There is nothing wrong with the `[bp]` option you simply need to move the environment earlier in the source so it comes on the page that you want.

Comment: Ok I think that was a secret. I moved the float object to Introduction, now its below the Methodology page. I thought I can be strict and really place the objects where it is referenced. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a package such as `dblfloatfix` to alow `figure*` to be placed at the bottom, an ddouble column floats appear at the earliest on the next page, so to foce it to appear on the page that you want, you may need to place it earlier in the source so that it is in the queue to be added when the page starts.